# How to Override Sproutcore's Namespace Captialisation

Tags: sproutcore

I'm working on a Sproutcore UI for a project called "BWUnit". When using sc-gen to create models, etc it converts "BWUnit" to "BwUnit" in the generated files. Is there a way to prevent this from happening so I don't have to manually edit the files, replacing "BwUnit" with "BWUnit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so SproutCore unfortunately doesn't support what you want out of the box. This is their naming convention: http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/27759680/FiedNotes-Suggestions%20on%20running%20the%20Sproutcore%20framework%20on%20a%20Windows%20(7)%20computer%20using%20a%20specific

If you are brave, however, you can edit the built tools and change the behavior of how the project and app names are prepared:
https://github.com/sproutcore/abbot/blob/master/lib/sproutcore/models/generator.rb#L462

If this is a feature you want and need, please open an issue here:
https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/issues

Cheers,

Johannes